# Overriding only the constructor of a class in Node

Tags: node.js, class, overriding

I'd like to override the default Error class without having to create a custom name for it. This should also apply to any other class though.

I tried to approach the problem like so:

```
var oldError = Error;
Error = function(msg, foo, bar){
    let err = oldError(msg);
    err.foo = foo;
    err.bar = bar;
    return err;
}
//new Error('error', 'lorem', 'ipsum'); -> now works
//foo and bar are totally optional. This way it sohuldn't break anything
//new Error(msg) -> still works
```

Doing so would override all Error methods though.

I could not call `Error.captureStackTrace` or any other one.

I would have to call `oldError.captureStackTrace`instead.

Is there a way to override only the constructor of the class and nothing else?

Comment: This is very bad design practice in any way. You should extend the class and manipulate it to your needs.

Comment: I'd just like to have a flexible constructor. Doing new Error(msg) would still work, because the other arguments are optional

Comment: So create you'r own Error handler class, and add whatever you want by extends the original Error class, this way you are not breaking anything and just add more functionalities to the base class as you need. Design Patterns exists for a reason.

Comment: How would my approach break anything? You could still do everything just like with the default class, but could choose to use the optional arguments.

Comment: @MateuszSowiński This may break third-party code that relies on that `Error` is native error and not a wrapper.

Comment: It wouldn't though? calling `Error(msg)` would result in the same thing. It's just an improved constructor with backward-compatibility

Comment: @MateuszSowiński 
You don't need to imagine all possible bad scenarios to know that the solution is bad. It's capable of breaking things, it doesn't benefit a developer, so it should be certainly avoided. I provided an example how it's possible to break things.

Comment: `It's just an improved constructor with backward-compatibility` not really backwards compatible, there are more cases where it would break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native objects should never be patched without a good reason - and even then they probably shouldn't.

Since it's expected that only you will use `Error` like that, extended error doesn't benefit from being available as global `Error`. It should be extended instead:

```
class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor(msg, foo, bar) {
    super(msg);
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

Patching error may break third-party code that relies on that `Error` is native class. The most obvious case is when native object is patched too late:

```
// third-party code that runs before patching
let err = new Error();
...
// patching
global.Error = class Error extends global.Error {...};
...
// third-party code that runs after patching
if (err instanceof Error) { /* the condition was expected to be true but it's not */ }
```

Comment: Foo and bar are only optional, I still don't understand why this would break anything? `new Error(msg)` would still work as intended, it's backwards-compatible. I'm literally just adding properties to the object to cut down on code length

Comment: It's already in the answer. `err instanceof Error === false` there, while it's supposed to be true. Something you're doing may have consequences you're not aware of. Consider it butterfly effect.

Comment: What if I had the Error class before any other code? That would prevent it, wouldn't it?

Comment: If you want to add a property in a backwards compatible way, you should use `Symbol`s, that are not enumerable, so it wouldn't break any code. Anyhow, you should extend `Error` as @estus explained.

Comment: It would prevent it, but you cannot control everything. That's why changing global behaviour is bad. A script that relies on native Error could be executed in a way it runs before yours, e.g. `node -r third-party.js`. Again, you don't need to know all possibilities to know they are possible. A good example is https://github.com/angular/zone.js . It patches native APIs to be as transparent as possible, still, there's a bunch of issues because you cannot foresee every problem that third-party code will cause, this was a doubtful approach from the beginning.